# Can I serve the contents of a static file directly as the Http response from a view?

Tags: python, django

I'm looking to return the contents of a static file as the (sometimes) HttpResponse from one of my views.

Is there a simple way to do this in Django?

Answer (score 3):

If the view sometimes does something with templating or any other calculations, then the best way will be to decide on the "sometimes" when you need to return a static object, and then issue a temporary redirect to that static url - this then leaves the server serving your static content the job of delivering the content.

**update**

Since I haven't used Django in a while, just generally web development etc... I have been informed that Django from 1.3+ includes a (what looks like) very easy redirect mechanism. (Simpler than what I recall anyway!)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/
*courtesy of Tadeck*

Comment: About redirecting: although you can use Django for serving static files and I agree with serving static files separately (see my answer for reasoning in both cases), redirection is really very easy since 1.3, especially because of `RedirectView` class-based view (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.RedirectView), which could be used directly in `urls.py` file without the need to write custom view. Plus it supports string interpolation and ability to separate permanent redirects from temporary ones.

Answer (score 2):

I really liked Jon Clement's idea. Though if you ever need to, this is how you serve a file:

```
def view(request):
    with open(path) as file:
        response = HttpResponse(file.read(), content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=filename.pdf'
        return response
```

Comment: Where does the system look for the file/what's the default search path for files served in this form?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way, in addition to what others have shown, this is sometimes used for returning responses for requests for `robots.txt`:

- in `views.py`:

  ```py
  from django.views.generic import TemplateView

  class RobotsTxtView(TemplateView):
      """A class-based view for responding to requests for robots.txt file
      """
      template_name = 'robots.txt'
      def render_to_response(self, context, **kwargs):
          """Overwritten render_to_response for applying text/html mimetype
          """
          return super(RobotsTxtView, self).render_to_response(context,
              content_type='text/plain', **kwargs)
  ```
- when you need a view (eg. inside `urls.py` or when trying to generate actual view), use this:

  ```
  from myapp.views import RobotsTxtView
  robots_view = RobotsTxtView.as_view()
  ```
- in `robots.txt` file in templates you can actually have static content (or anything you like).

But in general others are right: if you are serving static content, serve it as static content, do not use Django to process this file if you do not need that.

Comment: What version of Django is this based on? I used it extensively (or so I thought) before it had an official 1.0 release - and seems I'm learning a lot today about updates/new features...

Comment: @JonClements: It works on Django 1.4, but I believe it is compatible with at least 1.3. At least this is what documentation says: [Django: Class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/).

Comment: Might explain why I don't recall it from 0.9 and 1.0a then! Thanks for link - most appreciated.

Comment: @JonClements: You are welcome. There is also generic `RedirectView` class that you can use for easy / clean redirections, so maybe it could be useful somehow for doing what you proposed in your answer: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/

Comment: I have updated my answer with the link and an attribution to yourself - hopefully this will prove useful to someone else later. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 return HttpResponse("any content")
```

will do the trick rit? OR have I misundertood your question